# Trouble using qt function for P(-t<x<t)

Tags: r, statistics, stat

I have found very little information regarding this. I am new to statistical analysis and Rscript, so I am having trouble getting this to.

I am trying to find t for `P(-t<X<t) = 0.96` where `X ~t(11)` using the qt function

I've gone and found `P(X<t)` which gave me 1.928427, `qt(0.96,11)` but when I try to find `P(x<-t)` I get NaN. (I'm trying to solve `1-P = P(x<-t)` and then find the difference from `P(X<t)` and `P(X<-t)`

Am I approaching this from the wrong way all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `t(11)` distribution is symmetric, so you just need to find the point where half your probability lies below the lower threshold. For example

```
t <- abs(qt((1-0.96)/2, 11))
t
# [1] 2.32814
```

And you can verify that give the correct answer with

```
# P(T < t) - P(T < -t)
pt(t, 11) - pt(-t, 11)
# [1] 0.96
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand a lot better. Just wondering, why are we using the absolute function here? Is it because t can't be a negative value?

Comment: Well, since you are doing `P(-t<X<t)`, then `t` needs to be positive.